# Ionic: Having trouble displaying data from array

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

To keep it short I am creating a shopping cart like browser app. How its suppose to work:

1) User selects a product, at which point they are brought to the cart page.

- They can add the product to there cart, at which point they are redirected to the products page so they can add another product OR
- They can click the checkout button and they are brought to a order confirmation page where they can view every item in their cart

Problem: The array of items is passed in the `additem()` method to the `ConfirmOrder` but it is not printing out

Edit: Here is the working code. Thank you @rapropos on the ionic forum for the fix.

in my cart.ts file (The saveItem() method gets called when user presses the add to cart button

```
public items = [];
// Both of these params which are to be saved in the array are passed from another page
prodName:   string    = this.navParams.get('prodName');
prodDesc:   string    = this.navParams.get('prodDesc');

saveItem() {

  let newItem = {
    prodName: this.prodName,
    prodDesc: this.prodDesc
  };

  this.addItem(newItem);
}

addItem(item) {

  this.items.push(item);

  this.navCtrl.push(ConfirmOrderPage, items: this.items);
}
```

ConfirmOrder.ts

```
export class ConfirmOrderPage {

  prodName;
  items = [];

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public modalCtrl: ModalController) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad ConfirmOrder');

    this.items = this.navParams.get('items');
  }
}
```

ConfirmOrder.html

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items">{{item.prodName}}</ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

The OP has been updated with the fix. Thank you to  @rapropos on the ionic forums for the help. The fix was to add `items: this.items` so I could access the array on the receiving page

`this.navCtrl.push(ConfirmOrderPage, items: this.items);`